# Alguém me explica a medalha Eleitorado

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Eleitorado - Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas

Não entendi, tenho que votar em 600 perguntas e 25% dos votos totais tem que ser em pergunta? Como assim? Tenho que votar 600 ou 150 vezes? Não entendi

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu tenho uns 1000 votos, 50% rm perguntas, e não tenho essa medalha. Tem que ter ao menos 600 votos especificamente em perguntas.

Comment: @Renan É isso mesmo, meu comentário não foi 100% claro. Quis dizer: "Você tem que votar 600 vezes **em perguntas**, e do seu total de votos - digamos 1000 - 25% **ou mais** tem que ser em perguntas *(o que no caso seria 60%)*".

Answer (score 4):

A verificação desse "achievement" é feito a cada voto em perguntas. Você deve ter votado ao menos 600 vezes em perguntas, sim. E no mínimo um quarto dos seus votos deve ter sido em perguntas.

Exemplos:

- Annie tem 600 votos em perguntas e nenhum em respostas. Ela ganha a medalha;
- Bob tem 600 votos em perguntas, mas tem 5400 votos em respostas. Apenas 10% dos votos dele são para perguntas. Ele não ganha a medalha;
- Charlie tem 10 votos em perguntas e 10 em respostas. 50% dos votos dele são em perguntas, mas ele não ganha a medalha pois não teve 600 votos em perguntas ainda.

Comment: eu entendi, mas a frase está mal explicada